# Docker compose cannot run command service not running

Tags: docker-compose

I created docker-compose.yml which content you can find below. I navigate to the folder where file resist and run command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

This was shown:

```
Starting postgres ... done
```

then i run that query:

```
docker-compose ps
```

Result:

```
  Name                Command              State    Ports
---------------------------------------------------------
postgres   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Exit 1
```

Now i wanted to run some command:

```
docker exec -it postgres psql -h localhost -p 54320 -U robert
```

This is what i get:

```
Error response from daemon: Container ae1565a84bcf0b3662b47d4f277efd2830273554b6bcf4437129e33b31c88b35 is not running
```

Is my container not running or? please of support.
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
#  Create a service named db.
  db:
#   Use the Docker Image postgres. This will pull the newest release.
    image: "postgres"
#   Give the container the name my_postgres. You can changes to something else.
    container_name: "postgres"
#   Setup the username, password, and database name. You can changes these values.
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=robert
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=robert
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
#   Maps port 54320 (localhost) to port 5432 on the container. You can change the ports to fix your needs.
    ports:
      - "54320:5432"
#   Set a volume some that database is not lost after shutting down the container.
#   I used the name postgres-data but you can changed it to something else.
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you attempt exec

```
docker run -it postgres psql -h localhost -p 54320 -U robert
```

?

`$ docker exec --help`

Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

Run a command in a running container

Since your container has the status exit, you can't use docker exec

Comment: yes, this one i can, but this is not comming from docker compose..

Comment: @Henry docker-compose run -T postgres psql -h localhost -p 54320 -U robert

Comment: ERROR: No such service: postgres

Comment: exactly)))  docker-compose run -T db psql -h localhost -p 54320 -U robert

Comment: docker-compose run -T ***db*** psql -h localhost -p 54320 -U robert

Comment: psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this docker-compose file?

```sh
version: "3"

volumes:
    postgres_app: ~

services:
    #  Create a service named db.
    postgres:
        image: "postgres"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: robert
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: robert
            POSTGRES_DB: "mydb"
        volumes:
            - "postgres_app:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
        ports:
            - "54320:5432"
        restart: always
```

And this command `docker-compose exec postgres psql -U robert -d mydb`

I hope this will help!

On my computer i executed this file

[image]